# From universal measurability to measurability

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $K$ be a compact
>   metrizable space endowed with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra
>   $\mathcal{B}(K)$. Let $A\subseteq\Omega\times K$ be universally
>   measurable and such that $$C_\omega=\{x\in K:(\omega,x)\in A\}$$ is
>   closed for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Let $\Sigma_u$ the universal
>   completion of $\Sigma$.  Is it then the case that $A$ is in
>   $\Sigma_u\otimes \mathcal{B}(K)$?

I face the problem when I want to obtain a certain set-valued function that satisfies a strong measurability condition. It is enough for my purposes to get a closed-valued set-valued function with a graph measurable with respect to the completion on my underlying probability space. I can obtain the desired set-valued function as a projection, but this only gives me universal measurability of the graph.

As a first step, it might be intersting to know whether the conjecture holds in the case that $A(\omega)$ contains a single element for all $\omega$, so that it really is a function.

> If $f:\Omega\to K$ has a universally measurable graph, is $f$ then
>   $\Sigma_u$-$\mathcal{B}(K)$-measurable?

I have [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130456/from-universal-measurability-to-measurability) this now also on Mathoverflow.

Comment: Is $\Sigma_u = \Sigma \cup$ all sets that are measurable w.r.t. any complete measure on $\Omega$ whose domain contains $\Sigma$?

Comment: @hot_queen Yes, it is.

Comment: Is the following true: For every open set U in K, the set $\{\omega \in \Omega: A_{\omega} \cap U = \phi \}$ is in $\Sigma_u$? If not, then can you give an example where this fails?

Comment: @hot_queen That is actually the kind of measurability condition I want to end up with. In general, your condition implies the measurability of the graph. If $\Omega$ is standard Borel, I would get the desired measurability. For the general case, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that suffices for what I do. It is based on strengthening the assumption that the graph $A$ is universally measurable to it being analytic. The notion of analyticity being used is that a subset $S$ of a measurable space $(M,\mathcal{M})$ is analytic if there is a compact metric space $T$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(T)$ and a product measurable set $X\in\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{B}(T)$ such that $S=\pi_M(X)$, where $\pi_M$ is the projection onto $M$. Analytic sets are always universally measurable. This notion of analyticity is extensively developed in the book *Probability and Potential* by Dellacherie and Meyer. A nice guide to the essentials can be found in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2297861) (JSTOR required).

The countable intersection or union of analytic sets is again analytic. If an analytic set is analytic in the product of some measurable space and a compact metric space, then the projection on the first coordinate is again analytic. An important fact from the theory of set-valued functions on a measurable space is that if the values are closed subsets of separable metric space, then the following condition is sufficient for the graph to be product measurable: The set $$\{\omega:C_\omega\cap O\neq\emptyset\}$$ is measurable for each open set $O$.

So assume that $A$ is analytic and $O$ is open. Then $$\{\omega:C_\omega\cap O\neq\emptyset\}=\pi_\Omega \big(A\cap(\Omega\times O)\big)$$ and hence analytic by the facts above and therefore universally measurable.